# Create own library of C functions

Tags: c

I have been learning C for a couple weeks now (off and on).  My primary use will be data analysis.  I am surprised to find that simple functions are not available in the standard math.h library (e.g. average, mode, variance, etc.).  Granted, these functions are simple enough to write, but doing so EVERY time they are needed is cumbersome.

I could write my own header file (call it my_math.h) to store all of the non-standard functions, and include this file as needed.  I have two questions:

1. If I create a header file, how do I point my compiler to it?  Obviously, I would not want to have to copy the .h file to each project's directory.
2. Am I reinventing the wheel here?  Is there a standard library that has all of these functions pre-built?

Comment: GNU Scientific Library https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: You are a reinventing the wheel. There is almost everything you can think already written in C. For instance, the functionalities you requires are exposed by the **GNU Scientific Library (GSL)**

BTW the way you tell your compiler where to find the header differ from compiler to compiler. On GCC and clang -I <include directory> is sufficient.
Refer to the documentation of your compiler.

Comment: a `.h` file is not a library.

Comment: You include headers with `#include "my_math.h". The function declarations should be in the header file, but the function _definitions_ should be in a separate c file, such as my_math.c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a C-library (for Ubuntu) out of header- and source-files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252102/how-to-create-a-c-library-for-ubuntu-out-of-header-and-source-files)

Comment: You should use either static or dynamic libraries depending on your purpose, but as it is already said, `.h` are not libraries but header files. `.a` and `.so` are.

Comment: This is all very useful information, especially Lundin's comment.  I never would have guessed the functions are declared in the header, but actually defined in a separate .c file.  Greatly appreciated to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is by using a Makefile which makes the link between your *.c and your *.h. 
You have to declare your functions' headers into the *.h.
You can find some pieces of information here : 
[Makefile include header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440183/makefile-include-header) .

Answer (score 0):

Just open notepad and start writing your code without including any header files 
Even..... stdio.h..... also for example

```
void add(int x,int y)
{
return x+y;
}
Fun2()
{
}
Fun3()
{
}
```

After this just save the file with *.h 
the * sould be any file name you want 
Dont forget to paste this in "include" folder of your compiler